# Multiple exit msgbox's

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a message box to appear after a user verifies that they want to exit before the app closes. here is where I'm currently at,

```
private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?",
                        "Confirm exit...",
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Question,
                        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes)

    {
        decimal Discount;
        Discount = decimal.Parse(postDiscountCostTextBox.Text);

        if (Discount <= 999.99M)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This amount qualifies for 'A-100' frequent flier miles.",
                            "",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
    else    
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

`Discount = decimal.Parse(postDiscountCostTextBox.Text);`
Visual studio 2012 is pointing to the semicolon here, saying the input string is in the wrong format. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Type a proper number.  Use decimal.TryParse() to detect typing mistakes.

Comment: and how the strings  from that `postDiscountCostTextBox.Text`  looks like? try to input the correct value for that discount

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a two-phase process. First you could verify the thousands separator using the information in the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator` and `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes` throwing an exception if it doesn't pass and then pass the number into the `Decimal.Parse()`;

Answer (score 0):

solution to my problem can be found in another post I made:

[remove "$" when evaluating a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485487/remove-when-evaluating-a-textbox)