# remove "$" when evaluating a textbox

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a messagebox to appear after a user closes my app. This messagebox lets the user know something based on their purchase. My problem is that my program crashes when it reads the "$" in the textbox. Here is where I'm currently at:

```
    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if
        (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?",
        "Confirm exit...",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
        MessageBoxIcon.Question,
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes)

        {
            decimal Discount;
            Discount = decimal.Parse(postDiscountCostTextBox.Text);

            if (Discount <= 999.99m)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This amount qualifies for 'A-100' frequent flier miles.",
                    "",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }


        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

The program worked perfectly when I removed the "$" from the textbox, however, it needs to be there in the final product. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Another option is to make the dollar sign a label on the side of the textbox.. style it so it looks like it is part of the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
Discount = decimal.Parse(postDiscountCostTextBox.Text.Replace("$", ""));
```

Comment: Yeah, would have done it sooner but this site makes you wait a little bit after a post.

Comment: No problem...guess they want to prevent buyer's remorse :)

Answer (score 1):

What if the current culture on the system has a symbol other than a dollar sign for currency?

The correct approach is to specify the "Currency" NumberStyles and use TryParse() instead of Parse():

```
            decimal Discount;
            if (decimal.TryParse(postDiscountCostTextBox.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, null, out Discount))
            {
                if (Discount <= 999.99m)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This amount qualifies for 'A-100' frequent flier miles.",
                        "",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // ... invalid value in textbox ...
                // Dipslay a MessageBox?
            }
```